# Build Issues when implementing PSP22 token standard for ink! contract

Tags: ink, smart-contract

I am trying to implement the PSP22 token standard but getting errors when building my contract.
The errors are:

`#[brush::contract]`

`| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module psp22metadata_external`

`impl PSP22 for MyPSP22 {}`

`| ^^^^^ use of undeclared type PSP22`

`impl PSP22Metadata for MyPSP22 {}`

`| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared type PSP22Metadata`

`#[derive(Default, SpreadAllocate, PSP22Storage, PSP22MetadataStorage)] |`                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

`error: cannot find attribute` PSP22StorageField `in this scope`

I am following this tutorial put up [here](https://github.com/Supercolony-net/openbrush-contracts/blob/main/examples/psp22_extensions/metadata/lib.rs) via [here](https://docs.openbrush.io/smart-contracts/PSP22/Extensions/metadata/).

My brush crate version is v1.6.1

I noticed the import statement which is

`use brush::contracts::psp22::extensions::metadata::*;` is not resolving at all.

How can i go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out i was missing a features flag on my brush dependency. This solved it for me:

```
brush = { tag = "v1.6.1", git = "https://github.com/Supercolony-net/openbrush-contracts", default-features = false, features = ["psp22"] }
```